# assign unique id to dataframe elements

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a dataframe recording each person's name and address, denoted as

```
case class Person(name:String, addr:String)
```

dataframe looks like this,

```
+----+-----+
|name| addr|
+----+-----+
|  u1|addr1|
|  u1|addr2|
|  u2|addr1|
+----+-----+
```

but now I need to assign a `Long` type unique id to each element in this dataframe, which could be denoted as

```
case class PersonX(name:String, name_id:Long, addr:String, addr_id:Long)
```

and dataframe looks like this,

```
+----+-------+-----+------+
|name|name_id| addr|addr_id|
+----+-------+-----+------+
|  u1|      1|addr1|     2|
|  u1|      1|addr2|     3|
|  u2|      4|addr1|     2|
+----+-------+-----+------+
```

NOTE that, the elements in both columns (`name` and `addr`) share the **same id space**, which means, `name_id` should not have duplicates, and `addr_id` should not either, and furthermore `name_id`s & `addr_id`s should not overlap with each other.

How to achieve this?

Comment: Do you have another table, where do you want to reference? Or just every unique name or address has own id? You can try [string indexer](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/ml-features.html#stringindexer) but it makes unique id only for one column, not two (not same id space).

Comment: @JozefDúc, I need them unique for both columns, sadly this is required by GraphX, i.e. VertexId :-(

Comment: I faced the same problem few months ago - had vertices some strings, so I used `hashCode` function to convert them into integers

Comment: @JozefDúc, initially, I went with `hashCode`, however the graph is so large and I have lots of hash collision, which damaged the graph structure quite a bit, so I have to manually assign unique ids to the vertices before building the graph.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way to assign id is to use [`dense_rank`](https://databricks.com/blog/2015/07/15/introducing-window-functions-in-spark-sql.html) function from spark sql.

To make sure ids don't overlap between names and addresses you can make a trick:

- compute ids of names and addresses separately
- update ids of addresses by adding maximum id of name

In this way ids of addresses will be after ids of names

```
val input = spark.sparkContext.parallelize(List(
  Person("u1", "addr1"),
  Person("u1", "addr2"),
  Person("u2", "addr1")
)).toDF("name", "addr")

input.createOrReplaceTempView("people")
val people = spark.sql(
  """select name,
    |       dense_rank() over(partition by 1 order by name) as name_id,
    |       addr,
    |       dense_rank() over(partition by 1 order by addr) as addr_id
    |   from people
  """.stripMargin)
people.show()

//+----+-------+-----+-------+
//|name|name_id| addr|addr_id|
//+----+-------+-----+-------+
//|  u1|      1|addr1|      1|
//|  u2|      2|addr1|      1|
//|  u1|      1|addr2|      2|
//+----+-------+-----+-------+    

val name = people.col("name")
val nameId = people.col("name_id")
val addr = people.col("addr")
val addrId = people.col("addr_id")

val maxNameId = people.select(max(nameId)).first().getInt(0)
val shiftedAddrId = (addrId + maxNameId).as("addr_id")
people.select(name, addr, nameId, shiftedAddrId).as[PersonX].show()

//+----+-----+-------+-------+
//|name| addr|name_id|addr_id|
//+----+-----+-------+-------+
//|  u1|addr1|      1|      3|
//|  u2|addr1|      2|      3|
//|  u1|addr2|      1|      4|
//+----+-----+-------+-------+
```

Comment: could you please show me the code for my case here?